# Como enviar objeto por radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um radiobutton:

```
<input type='radio' onclick='clickRadioButton(this)' value='new object { nome = #: nome #}' />
```

Ele está retornando uma string, mas quero um objeto com a propriedade nome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria assim

```
<input id="but" type="radio" value='{"nome":"um nome","sobrenome":"um sobrenome"}'>
```

e o javascript

```
var radio = document.getElementById("but");
radio.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var _obj = JSON.parse(this.value);
    console.log(_obj);
});
```

A saída no console seria:

```
Object { nome: "um nome", sobrenome: "um sobrenome" }
```

[OUTRA FORMA DE FAZER]

Bom, se sua necessidade é esta, há uma forma melhor e mais segura que eu costumo utilizar que são os data-attributes.

Veja o exemplo abaixo. Utilizei a biblioteca jQuery para facilitar o acesso aos elementos da página, mas você pode utilizar a biblioteca que quiser ou JavaScript puro, tanto faz, só vai mudar a forma que se refere aos elementos:

```
<input type="radio" name="rd" id="rd-1" data-id="1" data-nome="um nome" data-sobrenome="um sobrenome">
<label for="rd-1">Radio 1</label><br>

<input type="radio" name="rd" id="rd-2" data-id="2" data-nome="um nome" data-sobrenome="um sobrenome">
<label for="rd-2">Radio 2</label><br>

<input type="radio" name="rd" id="rd-3" data-id="3" data-nome="um nome" data-sobrenome="um sobrenome">
<label for="rd-3">Radio 3</label><br>

<input type="radio" name="rd" id="rd-4" data-id="4" data-nome="um nome" data-sobrenome="um sobrenome">
<label for="rd-4">Radio 4</label><br>

<input type="radio" name="rd" id="rd-5" data-id="5" data-nome="um nome" data-sobrenome="um sobrenome">
<label for="rd-5">Radio 5</label><br>
```

e o javaScript:

```
$("input[name=rd]").click(function(){  
    // usando data-attributes
    var _obj = {id: $(this).attr('data-id'), nome: $(this).attr('data-nome'), sobrenome: $(this).attr('data-sobrenome')};
    console.log(_obj);
});
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/0t7w5Lp9/

Comment: Estou usando kendoTreeList e não consigo enviar os dados no value do radioButton com este exemplo.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues a solução do Walter é a maneira correta. Se tens mesmo de usar essa função inline no HTML podes usar como sugerido na resposta `var _obj = JSON.parse(this.value);` dentro dessa função e depois usar esse `_obj` onde fôr preciso.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar essa criação do objeto no value da input, por que você não utiliza uma função que crie um novo objeto?

```
function makeObj() {
    var obj = {
        nome: #
    };
    return obj;
}

<input type='radio' onclick='clickRadioButton(makeObj())' value='' />
```

Se a ideia é parametrizar de alguma forma a criação desse objeto com base na input, pode ainda enviar o this.value para o método makeObj e fazer a lógica de criação do objeto lá dentro. Exemplo:

```
function makeObj(nomeP) {
    var obj = {
        nome: nomeP
    };
    return obj;
}

<input type='radio' onclick='clickRadioButton(makeObj(this.value))' value='teste' />
```

Fonte: [SOen: JavaScript: function returning an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272239/javascript-function-returning-an-object)

Comment: infelizmente não é possível usar dessa maneira no meu caso, pois estou usando uma kendoTreeList e existe um radiobutton para cada linha. O objetivo é enviar os dados de cada coluna daquela linha através de um objeto.